# What is this weed with beautiful yellow flowers?

Tags: identification, urban-gardening

I live in subtropical Hong Kong. Is this some kind of tiny flower dandelion? Is has floating seeds, which grow in very small clusters about the same size as the flowers or smaller.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I can't be sure about the growing times. I threw so many random seeds in the ground and ignored everything and just moved everything around and am starting to get organized and serious about gardening.

I took a whole bunch of seeds and potted them hoping to grow a dozen or more. Would be great if it was not poisonous like my other purple weed I asked about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like "***Lactuca virosa***" which is commonly known as "**wild lettuce**". Although the plant in your photo seems small and could be a different Lactuca species. It is in the same family (Asteraceae) and same genus as edible lettuce (Lactuca sativa). This plant is "**biennial**", growing mainly in the first year and then flowering in the second year. The flowers are small, yellow, and attractive, but they are short lived as the plant goes to seed. This wild growing, common species is supposed to have analgesic properties. There are many online information sources about this, but methods of use and effectiveness vary. The links below offer more information and detail.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactuca_virosa

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactuca